# SFTP timeout issue while trying to copy csv file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure

I am trying to copy a csv file onto Blob storage but I keep on getting below issue even though I have set the timeout to 3 hours in my pipeline

```
 Copy activity encountered a user error at Source side: ErrorCode=UserErrorNetworkIssue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Meet network issue when connect to Sftp server '1XX.X.X.1', SocketErrorCode: 'TimedOut'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond,Source=Renci.SshNet,'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set the gateway in Linked Service.I set the gateway and the issue got resolved immediately.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how you resolve this issue? By adding some screenshot or somthing